# Google Apps Script, drag and drop individual gmail messages as .msg or .eml to another chrome tab

Tags: google-apps-script

I created the following Google Apps script to try and solve my problem but I cant seem to get an attachment or uri to represent the messages. Maybe Im going about it all wrong? I have another web app that takes file or uri input as a drag and drop but gmail wont let you drag and drop unless you download the message first, I thought this gmail add-on google apps script might solve that problem but the card attachemnt method errors and the data URI is missing from the resulting card:

```
function loadAddOn(event) {
  
  var accessToken = event.gmail.accessToken;
  var messageId = event.gmail.messageId;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  var mailMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  var eml = Utilities.base64Encode(mailMessage.getRawContent());

var attachment = CardService.newAttachment()
    .setResourceUrl("data:application/octet-stream;base64," + eml)
    .setTitle("Download .eml file")
    .setMimeType("application/octet-stream")
    .setIconUrl("https://mail.google.com/favicon.ico");

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Drag URL or attachment to other web apps"))
      .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
          .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("Download .eml file <a href=\"data:application/octet-stream;base64," + eml + "\"" + ">here</a>." + eml))
          //the above data uri does not show up in the card but he eml variable does contain the eml base64

          //.addWidget(attachment) //cant add attachment, results in error "Error with the add-on. Run time error. Exception: The parameters (CardService.Attachment) don't match the method signature for CardService.CardSection.addWidget. [line: 20, function: loadAddOn, file: Code]

          )
      .build();

  return [card];
}
```

Ive tried using card attachment and data URI, neither are working

I have improved the script but it still has issues.

1. Once a file has been removed using the button, that email can not be added back as a button or file. Its as if the event object is cached and wont trigger again.
2. After deleting a file, the card updates itself automatically but for the card to update after selecting an email, I must manually click the refresh button. Creative attempts to pop to root or refresh the card contents dont seem to work
3. The URL button and hyperlink both take you to a new browser window but dont download the file, you must refresh that browser tab or request the url again for it to actually initiate a download, maybe thats due to google wrapping URL's in its own request service?

```
// Function to create the homepage card with a list of files from the Google Drive folder
function createHomepageCard() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
      .setTitle('Files in Google Drive Folder')
    )
    .addSection(createFileListWidget())
    .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(createRefreshButton()))
    .build();

  return card;
}

// Function to create a widget displaying the list of files from the Google Drive folder
function createFileListWidget() {
  var folder;
  try {
    folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('temp').next(); // Get the folder named "temp"
  } catch (e) {
    // If the folder is missing, create it
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder('temp');
  }

  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet();

  var fileCount = 0;
  var zipFileBlob;

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    if (!fileName.endsWith('.zip')) {
      var fileNameParts = fileName.split('_'); // Split the filename by "_"
      var buttonName = fileNameParts.slice(0, -1).join("_"); // Join all parts except the last one
      var button = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText(buttonName) // Set the button name to only display the part before the last "_"
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
          .setFunctionName('deleteFile')
          .setParameters({ fileId: fileId })
        );
      buttonSet.addButton(button);
    }
    else {
      zipFileBlob = fileId; // Save the file ID of the zip file
    }
    fileCount++;
  }

  // Add a "Clear All" button if there are files present
  if (fileCount > 0) {
    buttonSet.addButton(CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Clear All')
      .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('clearAllFiles')
      )
    );
  }

  // Add a "Zip Files" button if there are files present
  if (fileCount > 0) {
    buttonSet.addButton(CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Zip Files')
      .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('zipFiles')
      )
    );
  }

  var section;
  if (fileCount > 0) {
    section = CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(buttonSet);
    if (zipFileBlob) {

      var downloadWidgets = createDownloadLink(zipFileBlob); // Using the modified createDownloadLink function

      // Extracting the paragraph and hyperlink widgets from the returned object
      var paragraph = downloadWidgets.paragraph;
      var hyperlink = downloadWidgets.hyperlink;

      // Adding the new CardSection containing both the paragraph and hyperlink to the main section
      section.addWidget(hyperlink);
      section.addWidget(paragraph);

    }
  } else {
    section = CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(
      CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('No files found. Please select an email to add files to the queue.')
    );
  }

  return section;
}


// Function to create a hyperlink for the zip file download
function createDownloadLink(blob) {
  var url;
  if (typeof blob === 'string') {
    // If the input is already a file ID, use it directly
    url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + blob;
  } else if (blob.getId) {
    // If the input is a Blob object, get its ID
    url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + blob.getId();
  } else {
    throw new Error('Invalid input for createDownloadLink function.');
  }
  
  // Construct HTML string for the link
  var html = "Click <a href='" + url + "'>here</a> to download .zip";

  // Create a paragraph widget with the HTML
  var paragraph = CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(html);

  var hyperlink = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Download Zip File')
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl(url));
  
  // Return an object containing both paragraph and hyperlink
  return {
    paragraph: paragraph,
    hyperlink: hyperlink
  };
  }

// Function to create a zip file and provide a link to Google Drive
function createZipFile() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('temp').next(); // Get the folder named "temp"

  // Check if there's an existing zip file and delete it
  var existingZipFiles = folder.getFilesByName('selected_files.zip');
  while (existingZipFiles.hasNext()) {
    var existingZipFile = existingZipFiles.next();
    existingZipFile.setTrashed(true);
  }

  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var blobs = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (!file.getName().endsWith('.zip')) {
      blobs.push(file.getBlob());
    }
  }
  var zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs, 'selected_files.zip');
  var zipFile = folder.createFile(zipBlob);

  // Refresh the card after creating the zip file
  var updatedCard = createHomepageCard();
  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNavigation(CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(updatedCard))
    .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
      .setType(CardService.NotificationType.INFO)
      .setText('Zip file created.'))
    .build();
}

// Function to handle zipping files when the "Zip Files" button is clicked
function zipFiles() {
  return createZipFile();
}

// Function to handle deleting a file when its button is clicked
function deleteFile(e) {
  var fileId = e.parameters.fileId;
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  file.setTrashed(true);

  // Delete any existing zip file
  deleteExistingZipFile();

  // Refresh the card after deleting the file
  var updatedCard = createHomepageCard();
  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNavigation(CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(updatedCard))
    .build();
}

// Function to handle clearing all files when the "Clear All" button is clicked
function clearAllFiles() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('temp').next(); // Get the folder named "temp"
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.setTrashed(true);
  }

  // Refresh the card after clearing all files
  var updatedCard = createHomepageCard();
  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNavigation(CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(updatedCard))
    .build();
}

// Function to go back to the root card (refresh)
function gotoRootCard() {
  var nav = CardService.newNavigation()
    .popToRoot()
    .updateCard(onHomepage());
  
  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNavigation(nav)
    .build();        
}

// Function to create a refresh button
function createRefreshButton() {
  return CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Refresh')
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('gotoRootCard')
    );
}

// Function to handle the event when an email is selected in the inbox
function onEmailSelected(event) {
  var messageId = event.gmail.messageId;
  var mailMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  var subject = mailMessage.getSubject();
  var body = mailMessage.getRawContent();
  var messageIdSuffix = messageId.split(':').pop(); // Get the part after the colon

  // Check if a file with the same name already exists
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('temp').next(); // Get the folder named "temp"
  var existingFiles = folder.getFilesByName(subject + "_" + messageIdSuffix + ".eml");

  // If a file with the same name already exists, skip the creation process
  if (existingFiles.hasNext()) {
    return;
  }

  // Create a .eml file in the Google Drive directory
  var emlFile = folder.createFile(subject + "_" + messageIdSuffix + ".eml", body);

  // Refresh the homepage card to display the new file button

  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setStateChanged(true) // Indicate that the state of the card has changed
    .setNavigation(CardService.newNavigation().popToRoot()) // Navigate back to the root card
    .build();

}



// Function to handle the event when the add-on is loaded
function onHomepage(e) {
  return createHomepageCard();
}

// Entry point for the add-on
function buildAddOn(e) {
  var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  var authorized = GmailApp.getUserInfo(accessToken).isCurrentUser;

  if (!authorized) {
    throw new Error('Access denied: Not authorized.');
  }

  // Set up event handler for email selection
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  return createHomepageCard();
}

// Function to delete any existing zip file
function deleteExistingZipFile() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('temp').next(); // Get the folder named "temp"
  var existingZipFiles = folder.getFilesByName('selected_files.zip');
  while (existingZipFiles.hasNext()) {
    var existingZipFile = existingZipFiles.next();
    existingZipFile.setTrashed(true);
  }
}
```